# How to modify the value from a QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

So I'm using a QDataWidgetMapper to map values from a QSqlQueryModel to widgets in my interface. This is working nicely, and each time my Model is updated or refreshed the widgets are updated too... Great!

But let's say that I have a QLabel... and this QLabel has been mapped to a field in the Model called 'City', and the text displayed by the QLabel in showing 'LONDON'. Is there a way to format this text so that it's displayed as 'London' instead? whilst also maintaining the mapping relationship, and without changing the database that the QSqlQueryModel is querying?

Thanks!

EDIT - Here's an simplified example of the code I have so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class DemoModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DemoModel, self).__init__()
        self.visibleColumns = ['city', 'country']
        self.items = [
            {'city': 'LONDON', 'country': 'England'},
            {'city': 'GLASGOW', 'country': 'Scotland'},
            {'city': 'CARDIF', 'country': 'Wales'},
            ]


    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)


    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.visibleColumns)


    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            colName = self.visibleColumns[index.column()]
            return self.items[index.row()].get(colName, '')


    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.visibleColumns[section]



class TestWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(100, 100)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        demoLabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(demoLabel)
        mapper.addMapping(demoLabel, 0, "text")



model = DemoModel()
mapper = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper()
mapper.setModel(model)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
demo =  TestWindow()
demo.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your example only shows an empty widget.

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah I'm a little confused about that myself. The model seems to be work when I view it in a QTableView... and from what I can tell the mapping is set up correctly. Very weird! The main difference between this example and my main code is that it's mapping from a QSqlQueryModel. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Put QSqlQueryModel and QTableView, I want to test it to give you some option but if I can reproduce it I will not be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set an item delegate on the data mapper, and re-implement the [setEditorData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html#setEditorData) method:

```
class ItemDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setText(index.data().title())

mapper = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper()
mapper.setModel(model)
delegate = ItemDelegate()
mapper.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

For this to work properly, the mappings must be made *without* specifying the property name:

```
mapper.addMapping(demoLabel, 0)
```

(Note that for editable display widgets, you might also need to re-implement the [setModelData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html#setModelData) method).